# How to solve Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I know that there are many guys asked this question, but I still could not resolve the issue even I tried all solutions that I found.
Basically, I have a micro-service named emms-core:
Here is bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
    application:
        name: emms-core
    cloud:
        config:
            fail-fast: true
            password: s3cr3t
            uri: http://localhost:8888
            username: root
    profiles:
        active: dev
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

spring cloud dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>`
```

Here is java code:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@Log4j2
public class EmmsCore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmmsCore.class, args);
        log.info("[Emms] Server started at " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "ping")
    public Mono<String> ping() {
        return Mono.just("pong");
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

Next, I setup a eureka server:

yml config:

```
eureka:
    client:
        fetch-registry: false
        register-with-eureka: false
server:
    port: 8761
spring:
    application:
        name: eureka-server
```

spring cloud dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

java code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegistry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistry.class, args);
    }

}
```

I could see my micro-service in eureka page:
[image]

Finally, I setup a Zuul proxy:

config:

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=zuul-server
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

zuul.ignored-services=*

zuul.routes.gallery-service.path=/emms-core/**
zuul.routes.gallery-service.service-id=emms-core

zuul.routes.auth-service.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

dependecies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

java code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class Proxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Proxy.class, args);
    }

}
```

I could see my Zuul proxy in eureka page:
[image]

When I tried to call `localhost:8762/emms-core/api/ping` I got an exception:

```
2021-04-04 19:02:30.571  INFO 29424 --- [nio-8762-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: emms-core instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=emms-core,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2021-04-04 19:02:30.578  INFO 29424 --- [nio-8762-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2021-04-04 19:02:30.580  INFO 29424 --- [nio-8762-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client emms-core initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=emms-core,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@43fc9527
2021-04-04 19:02:30.727  WARN 29424 --- [nio-8762-exec-1] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    ...
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: emms-core
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
```

As I said, I've already tried a lot of solutions that I found but no luck for now. Could you guys help me to solve this problem? I use spring cloud dependencies 2020.0.0

Comment: Zuul doesn't work with 3.0.x (2020.0)

Comment: Many thanks for your infomation. Could you please help to explain more?

Comment: Use Spring Cloud LoadBalancer instead. See documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer